# Installing ImageMagick on shared hosting

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm wondering if it's possible to use/install ImageMagick on shared linux hosting via GoDaddy. Specifically, the issue I'm running into is that I need to decode TIFF images, and GD does not support this. If it's not possible to install ImageMagick, as there an alternative approach to decoding TIFFs?

Comment: Are you sure that GoDaddy doesn't have Imagemagick installed? A quick Google search showed people were able to use it. Can you post the code you're having problems with?

You might try uploading this PHP script to verify ImageMagick is working: `<?php
exec("convert -version",$out,$returnval);
print_r($out[0]);
?>`

Comment: Ask your GoDaddy support

Comment: Looks like ImageMagick is installed but I still get an error that says ImageMagick class is not found

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code. The name of the class you should be instantiating is `Imagick`: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php

Answer (score 1):

Turns out ImageMagick was installed on our server, just not the PHP ImageMagick extension. Thankfully, we found a workaround without having to install the extension:

```
<?php
try {
$cmd = "full-path-to/input1.tiff full-path-to/input2.png"; 
exec("/usr/local/bin/convert $cmd");
}
catch(Exception $e) {
die('Error when creating a file: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```